# Xcode 5 NSTimer countdown removes 2 lives instead of 1

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, timer, countdown

Hello I am trying to make an advanced quiz game that counts down ex. 5 secs for every questions to answer and assings an apropriate amount of score like 10 if answered in 5 secs ,5 in 3 secs, and 1 if in 1 sec but my main problem is the counter works and a method i call to remove a live and start the wrong answer method all works but suddenly some times it removes like 2 lives instead of 1 and goes beyond my set limit of 0 for game over like -2 lives i can't figure it out could please somebody help me out ? would be appreciated so much and bit of noob in coding .
heres the code i use 
in my game.m  file

///////timer//////////////

```
-(void) timerRun {

    secondsCount = secondsCount - 1;
    //int minuts = secondsCount /60;
    int seconds = secondsCount;// - (minuts * 60);

    NSString *timerOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2d" ,  seconds];
    countDownLaber.text = timerOutput;

    if (secondsCount == 0) {
        [countDownTimer invalidate];
        countDownTimer = nil;

        [self LoseByTime];
    }    
}


-(void) setTimer{

    secondsCount = 5;
    countDownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerRun) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```

///////////////timer ///////////////////

```
-(void)LoseByTime{

    LivesNumber = LivesNumber - 1;
    Lives.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i" , LivesNumber];

}




-(void)RightAnswer{

    ScoreNumber = ScoreNumber + 50;
    Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i" , ScoreNumber];
    NextCategory.hidden = NO;
    Answer1.hidden = YES;
    Answer2.hidden = YES;
    Answer3.hidden = YES;
    Answer4.hidden = YES;
    QuestionText.hidden = NO;
    CategorySelected.hidden = YES;
    //Result.hidden = NO;
    //Result.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"transparentPic.png"];

}


-(void)WrongAnswer{

    LivesNumber = LivesNumber - 1;
    Lives.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i" , LivesNumber];
    NextCategory.hidden = NO;
    Answer1.hidden = YES;
    Answer2.hidden = YES;
    Answer3.hidden = YES;
    Answer4.hidden = YES;
    QuestionText.hidden = NO;
    CategorySelected.hidden = YES;
    //Result.hidden = NO;
    //Result.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"transparentPic.png"];


    if (LivesNumber == 0) {

        Result.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gameOver.png"];
        NextCategory.hidden = YES;
        Exit.hidden = NO;
        GameInProgress = NO;

    }



}


- (IBAction)Answer1:(id)sender;{

    if (Answer1Correct == YES) {
        [self RightAnswer];
        right1.hidden = NO;

    }
    else{
        [self WrongAnswer];
        wrong1.hidden = NO;


    }

}

- (IBAction)Answer2:(id)sender;{

    if (Answer2Correct == YES) {
        [self RightAnswer];
        right2.hidden = NO;



    }
    else{
        [self WrongAnswer];
        wrong2.hidden = NO;



    }

}

- (IBAction)Answer3:(id)sender;{

    if (Answer3Correct == YES) {
        [self RightAnswer];
        right3.hidden = NO;



    }
    else{
        [self WrongAnswer];
        wrong3.hidden = NO;


    }
}

- (IBAction)Answer4:(id)sender;{

    if (Answer4Correct == YES) {
        [self RightAnswer];
        right4.hidden = NO;



    }
    else{
        [self WrongAnswer];
        wrong4.hidden = NO;



    }

}
```

Comment: where's your code that calls setTimer? It sounds like you're calling it twice, which creates another timer without you invalidating it first. May explain why you sometimes have 2 lives removed at once

Answer (score 0):

In setTimer, I'd recommend invalidating and clearing countDownTimer to ensure that there is only one timer in existence at a time. Since the timer is currently only cleared when seconds count is zero, there is a possibility that setTimer is called before this occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and thanks for the reply i currently figured it out by adding [countDownTimer invalidate];
        countDownTimer = nil;
to my other methods as well on my "On wrong answer 
and in the if lives == 0 
and it seem to do the trick i guess it was invalidating the timer only if timer was at 0 and didn't stop the timer if you hit the wrong answer so hitting wrong answer didn't stop the timer which was counting to 0 and then removing a live as well so just had to invalidate timer even when another method was called 
Though i still didn't figure out how to make the score and timer to score depending on how much time you answered  :/